# TFS Online - TFS30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your TFS administrator

Tags: azure-devops

I and some of my colleges have started getting the following error on one of my TFS Online projects when I try to get all.

**The database is not correctly configured. Contact your TFS administrator.**

If I undo all my pending changes I can then get all, not always helpful.

Does anyone know of a proper solution?

Comment: By TFS Online do you mean Visual Studio Team Services (previously known as Visual Studio Online)?

Comment: Indeed I did mean exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this again. This issue should be fixed now. Refer to this link for details: [TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2429485)

> Posted by Wil [MSFT] on 3/3/2016 at 12:54 PM
>
> Thank you for letting us know. We deployed a fix just recently to fix
>   this issue. Please let us know if it is still occurring. Thank you
>   again for bringing this to our attention.